# IE7 RTL float right inside float left

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, right-to-left

I have a RTL document that has an element that has `float: left;` with `float: right;` elements inside it. IE7 does not render it correctly.

See demo and screenshots:

JS fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/R6aS5/](http://jsfiddle.net/R6aS5/)

Firefox (correct)

[image]

IE 7 - incorrect - the right floated elements are outside of their parent container

[image]

The element that is floated left (blue) must stay fluid. I know adding something like `width: 200px;` would fix it but the floated elements inside are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed via workaround of changing the inside elements that have `float: right;` - removed float and use `display: inline;` with `zoom: 1;` for IE7.

JS fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/8pFsZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/LW5xS/)

Renders as follows -

Firefox:

[image]

IE7:

[image]

Alternatively, could also use star hack to fix for < IE7 only instead of removing float property for all browsers:

```
li {
    float: right;
    *float: none;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
```